# how to remove ^[ character in vim and where are they come

Tags: vim

I have a file with content `xxx  - wwdebug0: xxxx`, when I use `cat xx.log | grep 'wwdebug0' > a.txt` to get all wwdebug0 fields out and use vim to open a.txt in Mac, the content become `- ^[[01;31m^[[Kwwdebug0^[[m^[[K:`.

So, 
Where does these `^[[m` like characters come from?
How can I remove these thing in the a.txt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^[[...` are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), which are used to highlight text in your terminal. They are introduced by `grep` to highlight the actual match.

Normally, `grep` would detect that you're redirecting the output into a file, and would turn off highlighting (`--color=auto`), but that somehow doesn't work for you (maybe because you have `--color=auto` in `GREP_OPTIONS`).

To fix that, either change your setup, or explicitly turn off the default options via

```
cat xx.log | GREP_OPTIONS= grep 'wwdebug0' > a.txt
```